# Read file with regular expression with start and end matching patterns

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I am reading `.sql` file and my requirement is to read the file and take the `INSERT` query from the `.sql` file when I used the regular expression it return only half of the query not the column value may be because of new line.

Return value:

```
Array ([0] => INSERT INTO `projects` (`id`, `project`) VALUES )
```

My code:

```
$sql_file_path = '/var/www/html/table.sql';
$fh = fopen($sql_file_path, 'r') or die($php_errormsg);
$pattern = "/INSERT INTO/"; 
while (!feof($fh)) 
{
   $line = fgets($fh, 4096);
   if (preg_match($pattern, $line))
    {
      $ora_books[] = $line; 
    }
}
fclose($fh);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($ora_books);
```

Please help me to create regular expression which reads all the insert query with column value also.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you make a pastebin of your file contents and point to it? **Don't add full file content here**.

Comment: What does the insert line look like? `strpos` would probably be easier to easy to test if a given string is inside a string. The `VALUES )` seems like the insert line might be an invalid query.

Comment: My sql query is look like:-

INSERT INTO `projects` (`id`, `project`) VALUES 
(1, 'demo_project');


INSERT INTO `streetviews` (`id`, `name`, `class`) VALUES
(1, 'Rishi','First'),(1, 'Raj','Second'),..........);

Answer (score 0):

Yes, fgets gets you a line so this wouldn't work if query spans across the lines. Just match on the whole file, use `/INSERT INTO[^;]+/` as pattern, supply third parameter (array) to preg_match and you'll get all the queries in that array.

I'd have to see the file to make exact pattern - if you have semicolons in the insert statement, find something else that marks the end of the insert statement, eg `);[\r\n]`